# Adding an app bar to a bottom navigation activity

Tags: android-studio

I want to add an app bar to my app which has a bottom navigation bar. I followed the android developer's help and here is what I made in my activity:

```
public class BetsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bets);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_p1:
                            selectedFragment = p1.newInstance();
                            Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
                            setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_p2:
                            selectedFragment = p2.newInstance();
                            myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
                            setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
                            break;
                    }
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                }
            });

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, p1.newInstance());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Activity's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.carbet.BetsActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my app manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo_car_bet"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_car_bet"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/logo_car_bet" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Car Bet"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BetsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bets"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />

</application>
```

I use fragments for the bottom nav bar but I don't do anything in their files.
When I launch it, first it shows a green bar, but without any title nor overflow menu. When I go to the other fragment, title appear but not the menu.
Please tell me which error(s) I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `AppBarLayout` with ToolBar within in the xml
and in Java code, Add this after `setContentView`

```
Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar_id)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and then inflate your Menu.